Azure DevOps build Artifact Error because of Failed to fetch ARM parameters: Error: Input required: AzureResourceManagerConnection
I want to build an Artifact via pipelines in Azure DevOps, but I have one warning and one error below.
warning:

WARNING === LocalFileClientService: Unable to read file: /home/vsts/work/1/s/template-parameters-definition.json, error: {"stack":"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/1/s/template-parameters-definition.json'","message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/1/s/template-parameters-definition.json'","errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"/home/vsts/work/1/s/template-parameters-definition.json"}

Error:

Failed to fetch ARM parameters: Error: Input required: AzureResourceManagerConnection

In my case, I only have one resource group, under the same repo, I have feature branch, develop branch and production branch. The template-parameters-definition.json file is in the workspace_publish. (I don't know why it cannot find it).
I want to build an Artifact when I trigger the pull request from develop branch to production branch.
For the AzureResourceManagerConnection, I have check it under the Service connections, we have set it up and name it:

devops-datalake-Development

here is the code for the yaml file:
trigger:
- production

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo-001
    type: git
    name: repo-001
    ref: refs/heads/production


steps:
  - checkout: repo-001
  - task: Synapse workspace deployment@2
    displayName: Validate Synapse workspace Artifacts
    inputs:
      operation: 'validateDeploy'
      ArtifactsFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      azureSubscription: 'devops-datalake-Development'
      ResourceGroupName: 'rg-dev-001'
      TargetWorkspaceName: 'workspace-dev-001'
      DeleteArtifactsNotInTemplate: true

  - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ExportedArtifacts
    artifact: SynapseArtifact

How could I debug it?
update:



The warning

WARNING === LocalFileClientService: Unable to read file: /home/vsts/work/1/s/template-parameters-definition.json, error: {"stack":"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/1/s/template-parameters-definition.json'","message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/1/s/template-parameters-definition.json'","errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"/home/vsts/work/1/s/template-parameters-definition.json"}

is just a warning instead of an error. template-parameters-definition.json is used to override the default parameter template and different from the TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json in the workspace_publish branch. This custom parameter template must be named exactly template-parameters-definition.json and placed in the root folder of your Git collaboration branch. It is not required. See the details from Azure Synapse Analytics CI/CD with Custom Parameters.
According to error "Failed to fetch ARM parameters: Error: Input required:AzureResourceManagerConnection", the issue seems to be related to the service connection. To verify this, you can click the Settings of task Synapse workspace deployment@2 -> select your subscription from drop down list "Synapse workspace connection type" -> click Authorize to create a new ARM service connection. Assign the service principle of the new ARM SC as workspace admin for your target workspace. Then run the pipeline again and check if it has the same error.


Hi Ziyang Liu, I have two options for Synapse workspace connection type, and the first one is services connection, which doesn't have authorize button. The other one is Subscription, and I choose one of them and when I click the Authorize, I get the error below:
Failed to create an app in Microsoft Entra. Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation in Microsoft Graph Ensure that the user has permissions to create a Microsoft Entra Application

the service connection and the subscription are the same, but why do I have authorize issue with the subscription and the service connection didn't work?

Hi @Joan, "the first one is services connection"- This is the service connection created by you before. Currently, it's not sure if the issue is related to this service connection. "The other one is Subscription" - When you click the Authorize, it will try to create a new ARM service connection. To do it, your account needs to have Application Administrator role in your target Azure Tenant. If you can't be granted this role, contact others having this role or the higher "Global Admin" role to try the above action.

Hi Ziyang, why the existing service connection( we shall grant proper permission) doesn't work for my case? How could I verify the service connection? I will update the setup of the service connection in my post.

"why the existing service connection( we shall grant proper permission) doesn't work for my case?", as mentioned, it's not sure whether the issue is cause by this service connection, currently. To narrow down the issue, it's suggested that you could have a try to create a new service connection following the steps above. I have tested several service connections from my side, but I haven't been able to reproduce the same error "Failed to fetch ARM parameters: Error: Input required:AzureResourceManagerConnection" in my pipeline.

Hi Ziyang, okay, I will try to create a new service connection and get back to you.

Sure. Feel free to let me know if you need any help or have any update.

Hi Ziyang, the bug is located on the Resources part, i have a refer on production branch, but I didn't update the yaml file in production branch. After I made a pull request from develop branch to production branch, it works well. Many thanks.

Hi @Joan, thanks for your update. It's great to know the issue is resolved. Happy coding!
